# notifications are not coming

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have the following class where a notification and a notification channel are created:

```
class NotificationUtils(private val context: Context) {

    private val channelId = "water_notification_channel"
    private val channelName = "Water Reminder"
    private val notificationId = 1
    private val alarmRequestCode = 100

    fun scheduleNotification() {
        createNotificationChannel()

        val intent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            alarmRequestCode,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)

        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 1,
            pendingIntent
        )
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    fun showNotification() {
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_circle_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content!")
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

I also have a NotificationReceiver class

```
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val notificationUtils = NotificationUtils(context)
        notificationUtils.showNotification()
    }
}
```

Added all permissions to AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WatterCount"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
        ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In MainActivity, in the onCreate method, I call with the following lines:

```
val notificationUtils = NotificationUtils(this)
notificationUtils.showNotification()
```

but the notifications are not coming.

I've tried to make simple notifications through button clicks, but they don't come either.

```
binding.smallMlStandart.setOnClickListener {
            
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext(), "channelID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_circle_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Content")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(requireContext())
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                notificationManager.notify(85223, builder.build())
            } else {
                
            }
        }
```